# sharepoint 2013 rest api upload image

Tags: javascript, 2013, rest, html5

I want to upload image or create image in Sharepoint 2013 document library using rest api (Javascript)

my code to get bite array from input type file element is

```
       var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {                   
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
            uploadfile(file.name, byteArray);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

// this is function to upload file

       function uploadfile(name, content) {

    var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    createitem.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Filer/Filer/Lists/DropBoard/" + currentuser + "')/Files/Add(url='"+ name +"',overwrite=true)",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/octet-stream", "x-requestforceauthentication": true},
        body: content,
        success: function () { alert("done"); },
        error: function () { alert("Error"); },        
    });    
}
```

when I upload image this error found in consol **Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.body.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved my problem 
Read file as an readAsArrayBuffer(file)
pass that file.target.result as buffer in _arrayBufferToBase64

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
var binary = ''
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)
var len = bytes.byteLength;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i])
}
return binary;
}
```

here return of binary variable pass as content in uploadfile function

```
   function uploadfile(name, content) {
  var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
createitem.executeAsync({
  url: appweburl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Tile of web/app title/Lists/list name/foldername')/Files/Add(url='" + name + "',overwrite=true)",
    method: "POST",
    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
    body: content,
    success: function (e) {            
        alert('done');
    },
    error: function () { alert("Error"); },
    state: "Update"
 });
}
```

Comment: How do I update/set metadata with this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the image to binary data which you can pass as content. 
One way is to use below :

```
function getBase64Image() {

      //if file:// dont work on your browser, you can find other alternatives.
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = "file:///c:/images/image-to-upload.png";

   // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to guess the
    // original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg" will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

Comment: i try both passing byte array  and base 64.
Image uploaded but corrupted. why?

Comment: try to remove the line dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""); from above function