# How to upload images to picture library using JavaScript?

Tags: 2013, development, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I want to upload multiple images to picture library using JavaScript.
I am building `SharePoint hosted app`. In which I have created a Picture Library in side Project Solution using Visual Studio and also I have added images in the same.

No I want to upload those image from my solution to picture library using JavaScript.

I have followed ***[this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/04/20/uploading-files-using-the-rest-api-and-client-side-techniques.aspx)***. But that has example which uploads file from file upload control. That is user needs to browse file and that file is going to be uploaded.

But I want to upload those files from my solution package.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: I have  given link for the blog that I have tried.

Comment: http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2013/02/using-jsom-to-write-small-files-to-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use server side code to upload images through imagining web service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcimaging.imaging.upload.aspx

2. Only file input () can convert the file into bytes and send them to server side.

So you have to use it or fileupload control in asp.net.

Comment: So I can not do this using JavaScript?

Comment: I think you can because using JS u can insert to lists also,so this should be possible,but i haven't tried my self.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the image to picture library using REST or JSOM.

solution using REST, find [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54218/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-upload-image).

And using JSOM, find [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/eaf02370-8be8-4355-aecd-65346847ae48/how-to-upload-image-to-picture-library-using-javascript?forum=appsforsharepoint).

please upvote if this answer helped you in any way.